# Good place to join a thread on a disposable class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable

I've got a class that implements the IDisposable interface and the dispose pattern. In the constructor I create a thread that will be running for the objects life time. I want the thread to be joined and killed when the class is disposed. The class has a finalizer because I'm using some unmanaged code. Where is the best place to place the JOIN?

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            writerThread.RequestStop(); //tells the thread to stop
            writerThread.Join();
        }

        // I think is better here in case Dispose is never called ??
        // writerThread.RequestStop(); //tells the thread to stop
        // writerThread.Join();

        // free unmanaged resources 


        disposedValue = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmya, this is IDisposable abuse.  An interface whose contract says that calling Dispose() is *optional*.  Does it still work okay when the client code does not call it?  Always very high odds for deadlock when you do this since if you make this call from the UI thread of a program it is no longer responsive and Invoke() calls are going to hang.  So there isn't any real good place to call it.  Never hide a threading implementation detail behind an innocent looking method call.

Comment: Don't do that. You have no garantee that `writerThread` hasn't been already collected if you put it outside the `if`. Remember, the finalizer can be who called `Dispose(false)`, all bets are off on what is the real state of  the managed references you might have.

Comment: I think that you can simply call the `Abort` method in `if` clause, without joining, as the finalizer is being run in case that the resources may be unavailable. Also, you may consider to inherit the [CriticalFinalizerObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx) for ensuring all finalization code in derived classes is marked as critical.

Comment: Finalizers are unlikely to work usefully when used to wrangle threads.  As often as not, an object won't become eligible for finalization unless or until things have been cleaned up well enough as to make it unnecessary.